# How to prevent regmatches drop non matches?

Tags: regex, r

I would like to capture the first match, and return `NA` if there is no match.

```
regexpr("a+", c("abc", "def", "cba a", "aa"), perl=TRUE)
# [1]  1 -1  3  1
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1]  1 -1  1  2

x <- c("abc", "def", "cba a", "aa")
m <- regexpr("a+", x, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(x, m)
# [1]  "a"  "a"  "aa"
```

So I expected "a", NA, "a", "aa"

Comment: I thought you wanted either the first match or an NA but nothing else? There seems to be confusion. This illustrates the need for greater precision in posing questions, preferable with the exact output that is requested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Staying with `regexpr`:

```
r <- regexpr("a+", x)
out <- rep(NA,length(x))
out[r!=-1] <- regmatches(x, r)
out
#[1] "a"  NA   "a"  "aa"
```

Answer (score 14):

use `regexec` instead, since it returns a list which will allow you to catch the `character(0)`'s before `unlist`ing

```
 R <- regmatches(x, regexec("a+", x))
 unlist({R[sapply(R, length)==0] <- NA; R})

 # [1] "a"  NA   "a"  "aa"
```

Comment: `unlist({R[lengths(R)==0] <- NA; R})` works now too since the introduction of `lengths()` in recentish R versions.

Answer (score 7):

In R 3.3.0, it is possible to pull out both the matches and the non-matched results using the invert=NA argument.  From the help file, it says

> if invert is NA, regmatches extracts both non-matched and matched substrings, always starting and ending with a non-match (empty if the match occurred at the beginning or the end, respectively).

The output is a list, typically, in most cases of interest, (matching a single pattern), `regmatches` with this argument will return a list with elements of either length 3 or 1. 1 is the case of where no matches are found and 3 is the case with a match.

```
myMatch <- regmatches(x, m, invert=NA)
myMatch
[[1]]
[1] ""   "a"  "bc"

[[2]]
[1] "def"

[[3]]
[1] "cb" "a"  " a"

[[4]]
[1] ""   "aa" ""
```

So to extract what you want (with "" in place of NA), you can use `sapply` as follows:

```
myVec <- sapply(myMatch, function(x) {if(length(x) == 1) "" else x[2]})
myVec
[1] "a"  ""   "a"  "aa"
```

At this point, if you really want NA instead of "", you can use

```
is.na(myVec) <- nchar(myVec) == 0L
myVec
[1] "a"  NA   "a"  "aa"
```

---

*Some revisions*:
Note that you can collapse the last two lines into a single line:

```
myVec <- sapply(myMatch, function(x) {if(length(x) == 1) NA_character_ else x[2]})
```

The default data type of `NA` is logical, so using it will result in additional data conversions. Using the character version `NA_character_`, avoids this.

An even slicker extraction method for the final line is to use `[`:

```
sapply(myMatch, `[`, 2)
[1] "a"  NA   "a"  "aa"
```

So you can do the whole thing in a fairly readable single line:

```
sapply(regmatches(x, m, invert=NA), `[`, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using more or less the same construction as yours -

```
chars <- c("abc", "def", "cba a", "aa")    

chars[
   regexpr("a+", chars, perl=TRUE) > 0
][1] #abc

chars[
   regexpr("q", chars, perl=TRUE) > 0
][1]  #NA

#vector[
#    find all indices where regexpr returned positive value i.e., match was found
#][return the first element of the above subset]
```

Edit - Seems like I misunderstood the question. But since two people have found this useful I shall let it stay.

Comment: Some explanation of why and how this works would be good (hint, hint)

Comment: I think Johan's point (hint) is that this is not quite returning what the OP is requiring

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr::str_extract(string, pattern)`. It will return NA if there is no matches. It has simpler function interface than `regmatches()` as well.