# R extract string from data.table column

Tags: r, string, split, data.table, extract

This post is a continuation from [R search subset string from data.table column for Capitalized words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273230/r-search-subset-string-from-data-table-column-for-capitalized-words/65273253?noredirect=1#comment115398465_65273253)   I need to add more conditions into this.
A Sample Data.tabel would be

```
dt <- data.table(Msg= c("SOMENote: THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of Message",
                       "SOMENote: THIS-IS Not Important. THIS_IS Rest of Message",
                       "SOMENote: no_string_here.. THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of Message",
                       "SOMENote: THIS_HAS_110KV_Numbers. Rest of Message"))
output <- c("THIS_IS_IMPORTANT",
            "THIS_IS",
            "THIS_IS_IMPORTANT",
            "THIS_HAS_110KV_Numbers")
```

I want to Extract From the *Message*  the string in the form **THIS_IS_IMPORTANT** which can appear anywhere in the *Message* after `"SOMENote:"`.
The format also has numbers in some rows, like **THIS_100L_HAS_NUMBERS**.
In general, the Capitalized words with underscore between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub`, `regexpr` with `regmatches` to extract the hit:

```
y <- sub(".*:[^A-Z]*", "", x) #Remove eveything until : and not A-Z
regmatches(y, regexpr("[A-Z0-9]+_\\w*", y))
[1] "THIS_IS_IMPORTANT"      "THIS_IS"                "THIS_IS_IMPORTANT"     
[4] "THIS_HAS_110KV_Numbers"
```

Data:

```
x <- c("SOMENote: THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of Message",
       "SOMENote: THIS-IS Not Important. THIS_IS Rest of Message",
       "SOMENote: no_string_here.. THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of Message",
       "SOMENote: THIS_HAS_110KV_Numbers. Rest of Message")
```

Comment: The actual Text does not have any single keyword such like ```THIS_```.  But the pattern appears after a ```:``` Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Yes, It is. Thank you

Comment: How can I get over ```NA```  in this? Some of the rows has NAs and it shows an error that the replacement has lesser number of rows. ```Input ` ` can't be recycled to size ```

Comment: See: [How to prevent regmatches drop non matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19171715/10488504)